# OData URI to JSON mongoDB query

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, odata

I'm doing a project with nodejs and mongoDB. In a get method, the client send me an OData uri for exemple

```
http://localhost:8080/persons?$filter=name eq 'test'
```

Now I want in my application to transform the result of $filter in a mongoDB object like this

```
var filter = {"name" : "test"}
```

and put that object in a find query like this

```
db.collection.find(filter)
```

That is just a simple example but in my application it is more complicated that. see http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions
I'm asking if it exists a npm module to do that or do i have to do it manually something that will be complicated. Bref, I'm asking for the better solution for doing that.
 thanks

Comment: Any results, did you proceed with this project?

Comment: Someone helped me with Kendo's Grid translation [here](https://github.com/Kinvey/kinvey-kendo-data-source/blob/07b7b95353439498f9c27f8d6a6f5aa0a3733af9/kendo.data.kinvey.js#L176).  It could be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, there are two aproaches for this and it depends on how you need to use the GET requests, as you can see in the link you provided, the request is formed by a URL, tha is the domain right up to the first /, then the path, and that's all of the parameters between slashes ( / ), and finally the query, and that's  whatever comes after "?"

What you are saying in your question is that you need a full query embedded in a single query parameter, the only use case I could fin that useful is if you will be using other query parameters for other things (even there some rethink should be done to handle simpler tasks).  Any way, if that's the way you need it, I would recomend to send a urlencoded JSON.strigify processed object with the query you need and then and urldecode, parse it server side, that's the easiest way.
http://www.yourDomain.com/persons?$filter=%7B%22name%22%3A%22test%22%7D

```
app.get("/persons", function(req, res){

    console.log(req.query); // Should output {filter : "%7B%22name%22%3A%22test%22%7D"}
    var query = req.query;
    query = decodeURIComponent(query.filter);
    query = JSON.parse(query);

    db.collection("persons").find(query).toArray(function(error, result){
        if(error){
            res.status(500).send("Database problem");
        } else if(result.length == 0){
            res.status(204).send("No content");
        } else {
            res.json({result : result}); // Embedded in an object for security reasons
        }
    });
});
```

On the other hand, if you need the query and that's all, then you are complicating your self more than needed.  The proper way of using a GET request is exactly to perform queries, for example:
http://www.yourDomain.com/persons?name=test

If you do it that way and you use a framework like express, well it's the easiest thing... In the path resolver, you get the query from the request object, and that's it, for example:

```
app.get("/persons", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query); // Should output {name : "test"}
    db.collection("persons").find(req.query).toArray(function(error, result){
        if(error){
            res.status(500).send("Database problem");
        } else if(result.length == 0){
            res.status(204).send("No content");
        } else {
            res.json({result : result}); // Embedded in an object for security reasons
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok if I undersand well you preconize me to send a urlencoded JSON.strigify or using simple get method and let down sendind my url via OData method ??

Comment: Yeah, according to the documentation, you should embed, that's not the most elegant or standard way to work with, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Although, searching a bit, I found this library https://github.com/qraftlabs/node-odata-parser that parses the requests, take a look and let me know.

Comment: I've seen it's not what i want. Suppose that I use your first method. If I give a query like that in the url `{"libelle": "test"}`, it will work fine but il I give a negative form like this: `{"libelle": {$ne: "test"}}` it won't work because I will have a JSON parse error du to the $.

Comment: Finally its working. I've to put the $ne between quotes so I will have something like that: `{"libelle": {"$ne": "test"}}`<br>
For now I will use that solution but if I have a solution for how to use OData URI it will be better. Thanks for your help @jmdiego